# Checking if row already exists

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, validation, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to make validation for a registration form to check whether a username/name + surname already exists.

This is what I tried:

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=BRIAN-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master_db;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim registerSQL As SqlCommand
    Dim checkCredentialsSQL As SqlCommand
    Dim sqlComm As String
    Dim sqlCommName As String
    Dim sqlCommUsername As String

    sqlComm = "INSERT INTO users(Username, Password, Name, Surname, Address1, Address2, " +
        "City, Country, date_of_birth, age, Occupation, department, work_location, " +
        "project_manager,team_leader, team_leader_id, project_manager_id, " +
        "date_registration, contract_type, contract_duration) " +
        "VALUES(@p1, @p2,@p3,@p4,@p5,@p6,@p7,@p8,@p9,@p10,@p11,@p12,@p13,@p14,@p15," +
        "@p16,@p17,@p18,@p19,@p20)"

    sqlCommName = "SELECT name, surname FROM users WHERE name='" + txtName.Text + "' and surname='" + txtSurname.Text + "'"
    sqlCommUsername = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='" + txtUsername.Text + "'"

    conn.Open()

    checkCredentialsSQL = New SqlCommand(sqlCommName, conn)


    If checkCredentialsSQL.ExecuteScalar IsNot Nothing Then

        lblName.Text = txtName.Text + " " + txtSurname.Text + "is already registered."
        lblName.Visible = True


    Else

        checkCredentialsSQL = New SqlCommand(sqlCommUsername, conn)

        If checkCredentialsSQL.ExecuteScalar IsNot Nothing Then

            lblUsername.Text = "'" + txtUsername.Text + "' is already taken."

        Else


            registerSQL = New SqlCommand(sqlComm, conn)
            registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Username)
            registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", Password)
            registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", Name)
            registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", Surname)
            registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", Address1)
            registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", Address2)
            registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", City)
            registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8", Country)
            registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p9", DOB)
            registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p10", Age)
            registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p11", Occupation)
            registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p12", Department)
            registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p13", WorkLocation)
            registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p14", ProjectManager)
            registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p15", TeamLeader)
            registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p16", TeamLeaderID)
            registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p17", ProjectManagerID)
            registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p18", RegistrationDate)
            registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p19", ContractType)
            registerSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p20", ContractDuration)

            registerSQL.ExecuteNonQuery()



        End If

    End If

    conn.Close()
```

Is it viable/safe/recommended to do it as that?

Comment: I personally would place the functionality of all 3 of these into a single Stored Procedure in SQL Server.

Comment: Why do you have parameters for one command and use string concatenation for the others? You already know that is not secure to pass strings in that way

Comment: @MartinParkin And I could still output an "error message" on the page that way? Do you have any good tutorials?

Comment: I hate to break this to you, but it is possible for more than one person to share the same combination of name and surname.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple stored procedure that checks the two conditions you want to check (more on that below):

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CreateUser
  @username NVARCHAR(255),
  @name     NVARCHAR(64),
  @surname  NVARCHAR(64)
  /* ... other params ... */
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.users WHERE username = @username) 
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Username %s is already registered.', 11, 1, @username);
    RETURN -1;
  END

  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.users WHERE name = @name AND surname = @surname) 
  BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Name %s %s is already registered.', 11, 1, @name, @surname);
    RETURN -2;
  END

  BEGIN TRY
    INSERT dbo.Users(username,  name,  surname,  ...other columns...)
             SELECT @username, @name, @suername, ...other params...;
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @msg NVARCHAR(255) = ERROR_MESSAGE();
    RAISERROR(@msg, 11, 1);
    RETURN -3;
  END CATCH
END
```

Now your VB.Net code is much simpler:

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection("...conn string...")
conn.Open()
Dim sql As New SqlCommand("dbo.CreateUser", conn)
sql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
rv = sql.Parameters.Add("@rv", SqlDbType.Int)
rv.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue    

sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username)
sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",     Name)
sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname",  Surname)
... other params ...

sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
Debug.Print "Return value: " & rv.ToString

...act accordingly depending on error raised and/or return value     
...maybe you want TRY/CATCH here?

conn.Close()
```

While attempting to insert (with a `WHERE` clause, or just letting constraints raise errors) might be a technically possible approach, I don't think it's a good idea. The first because your code can't tell you which condition caused the problem, and the second because it is very expensive to let SQL Server raise the exception for you:

- [Performance impact of different error handling techniques](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/error-handling)
- [Checking for potential constraint violations before entering SQL Server TRY and CATCH logic](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2632/checking-for-potential-constraint-violations-before-entering-sql-server-try-and-catch-logic/?utm_source-AaronBertrand)

That doesn't mean you shouldn't have the underlying constraints, of course. They should be there for cases where users don't go through your stored procedure, application tier, etc.

Oh and I agree with others. Do you really think only one John Smith will ever register? Having the same name as someone else is not a very valid reason to prevent someone from registering IMHO.

---

PS I apologize if my VB.Net code is far from perfect. I don't write in VB and some of that is an educated guess...

Comment: Your vb code is well written. it explains in detail how to raiseerror in SQL and grab it within .NET.

Answer (score 0):

The `sqlCommName` command isn't secured against SQL injections. if `txtName.Text` contains `existing_username AND 1 = 0` the user could be registred twice.

Answer (score 0):

Although I disagree with the criteria that you're using (because name+surname is almost certainly *not* a unique identifier for a person), the general form should be an attempted `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO TabA (Val1,Val2,Val3)
SELECT @Val1,@Val2,@Val3
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TabA where Val1 = @Val1 or (Val2 = @Val2 and Val3 = @Val3)
```

Otherwise, you're still exposing yourself to race conditions.

And, depending on what concurrency settings you're running under, you may *still* need to deal with constraint violations (I assume you *are* enforcing any uniqueness constraints that you do have down at the database level also)